# Typing domain with www breaks jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, dns, subdomain

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin on the site http://hskinsurance.com to cycle through the main image, but I just noticed that if I type the domain as http://www.hskinsurance.com, the plugin doesn't work - http://cl.ly/image/3R2J1A3D3g0H

Everything else seems to load fine except the cycle plugin, which is hosted on github...

http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js

So I'm guessing the issue lies with the script being on github, or the .htaccess line I have that rewrites www as a naked domain. Any ideas how to fix this? It seems to be a Chrome / Safari issue; I can't reproduce it in Firefox and don't have IE.

Thanks!

Comment: Just host it on your server or use `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/2.9999.8/jquery.cycle.all.min.js`. It's not working whether you include `www` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that If you download that plugin, host it in your site and include it in your markup, everything will be fine ;)

In Chrome console these are the errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)       http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input [VM] 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
```

So I guess that path isn't made to be included

Comment: Fixed it, thanks a lot! Next time I'll just test in console myself - oops :)

Comment: @Chris: Ye, It's an essential tool to develop client side ;)